# How do I remove a css style (id) that was previously created?

Tags: javascript, html

With `addStyle()` I add some css styles to a website. Any subsequent calls to that function should remove the previously added style. `removeChild()` is supposed to do that be it is not working. What am I missing here?

```
function addStyle(style) {

    var css = document.getElementById("my_css");
    if(!css){
        css = document.createElement('style');
        css.id = 'my_css';
        css.type = 'text/css';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(css);
    }

    css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(style));
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);

}

var someStyle = `
input {
   color: green;
}
`;

addStyle(someStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your function a bit, to be able to pass any id. Hope it helpes

```js
function addStyle(style, id) {

  let div = document.getElementById(id);
  //only for printing purpuse
  let bodyElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

  if (!div) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = id;
    div.innerHTML = id + '_text'
  } else {
    console.log("before remove ", bodyElements)
    div.remove()
    console.log("after remove ", bodyElements)
  }

  div.style.cssText = style;
  div.innerHTML = id + '_text'
  // getElementsByTagName("body") contains nothing in this case so i specified 
  // to take all elements by using *
  document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].appendChild(div);

  console.log("after style add ", bodyElements)
}

var someStyle1 = `color: red;`;
var someStyle2 = `color: green;`;

//existing id, will be removed and the below will be appended
addStyle(someStyle1, 'my_css_1');

//new element, the below will be appended
addStyle(someStyle2, 'my_css_3');
```

```html
<div id="my_css_1">div1</div>
<div id="my_css_2">div2</div>
```

After the comment i've edit the snippet to apply the given style based on tag name (delete the existing tags, apply new style and append back)

```js
function addStyleToElements(style, tagName) {

  let elements = [];
  //ES6 can use forEach for NodeList, but not for HTMLCollection so we transform in array
  elements = [...document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)]

  if (elements.length === 0) { //no element with given tag
    let newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    newElement.innerHTML = tagName + '_' + 'new_element';

    elements.push(newElement);

  } else { //remove all elements with given tag
    elements.forEach((e, i) => {
      e.remove()
    });
  }

  elements.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.style.cssText = style;
    if (!e.innerHTML) e.innerHTML = tagName + '_' + i;
    document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].appendChild(e);
  });
}


let someStyle1 = `color: red;`;
let someStyle2 = `color: green;`;
let someStyle3 = `color: blue;`;


//existing element, will be removed and the below will be appended
addStyleToElements(someStyle1, 'div');

//existing element, will be removed and the below will be appended
addStyleToElements(someStyle3, 'h4');

//new element, the below will be appended
addStyleToElements(someStyle2, 'h3');
```

```html
<div id="my_css_1">div1</div>
<div id="my_css_2">div2</div>
<div id="my_css_3">div3</div>

<p id="my_css_4">p1</p>
<p id="my_css_5">p2</p>

<h4 id="my_css_5">h4</h4>
```

If you don't want to remove the entire element but to change only the style of it, the code should look like this:

```js
function addStyleToElements(style, tagName) {

  let elements = [];
  //ES6 can use forEach for NodeList, but not for HTMLCollection so we transform in array
  elements = [...document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)]

  elements.forEach((e, i) => {
    //overwrite the existing style
    e.style.cssText = style;
  });
}

let someStyle1 = `color: red;`;
let someStyle2 = `color: green;`;

//existing element, will be removed and the below will be appended
addStyleToElements(someStyle1, 'div');

//existing element, will be removed and the below will be appended
addStyleToElements(someStyle2, 'p');
```

```html
<div id="my_css_1">div1-test</div>
<div id="my_css_2">div2</div>
<div id="my_css_3">div3-test-test</div>

<p id="my_css_4">p1</p>
<p id="my_css_5">p2</p>

<h4 id="my_css_5">h4</h4>
```

Comment: The style is only applied to a certain element. What I'm looking for is a way to inject css into the document that is applied to any element. E.g. all input elements will get a certain color etc.

Comment: @smolo I did some changes, if i misunderstood let me know and i'll try to help